# I split single day of Fullcalendar view in multi column dynamically

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, yii

I create the agenda event management using full calendar.i want split the day view as multi-column  based on number of events location. i split statically but i need to split dynamically .my code for split statically as given bellow.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'resourceDay'
  },
   defaultView: 'resourceDay',
  resources: [
    {
      /*
       * employeeId
         * name
         * backgroundColor
         * foregroundColor
       */
      id: '1',
      name: 'Joe Bloggs',
      color: 'red',
      textColor: 'black'
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      name: 'Alan Black',
      color: 'blue'
    },
    {
      id: '3',
      name: 'Robert White',
      color: 'pink'
    },
    {
      id: '4',
      name: 'Paul Green',
      color: 'green'
    },
    {
      id: '5',
      name: 'Jane Yellow',
      color: 'yellow',
      textColor: 'black'
    }
  ],
  events: [
    {
          title: 'Test Event',
        start: '2014-03-27 12:30:00',
        end: '2014-03-28 17:10:00',
        resources: '4',
        allDay: false

            }
        ],
    });


  });
</script>

 <div id='calendar'></div>
```

above code work fine but i want to give resource value as dynamically.
please help me..

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a requirement of passing dynamic event data. I refer the below link that gives example of getting data from ajax request. I hope it will help you resolve your problem of getting dynamic data.

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_function/